# Socket communication between Android app and Python script

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm looking for a way to make a kotlin client connect to a python IPv4 server over wifi and I want to be able to send data from the client to the server. I'm fairly new to Kotlin and don't really know what I should be looking for. I'm going to use the kotlin code for an android wear app, if that matters.

Comment: `I'm looking for a way to make a kotlin client connect to a python IPv4 server over wifi...` You can use sockets for that.

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to use them well in kotlin since I'm new to the language

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have

- Python script running on server side, serving an API
  (which could be based on [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) for instance)
- Kotlin android app as a client

Then sockets seems not the easiest way to go.
You could directly target your python API with kotlin using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).
It is the right tool for the job, and you'll find tons of tutorials online for this.

This is because Android already abstracts all the low level network stack (sockets) for you.